# I need a python function to depth first search into a dict of lists of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, depth

I have this data structure, a dict composed by lists of lists (a sort of tree structure), in which the letters are phrases:

```
dict = {
   'A': [ ['A1', ['A2'], ['A3', ['A4'], ['A5'] ] ],
   'B': [ ['B1', ['B2'] ],
   'C': [ ['C1', ['C2', ['C3'] ], ['C4'] ] ]
}
```

What I need is a function that returns the 'list of list of elements from a root to a leaf'.

In other words, I need to explore the entire tree following each path, concatenating the phrases reconstructing the conversation.

This tree structure was constructed by crawling Reddit, so each path is a sequence of answers, so a single conversation.

For key 'B' there is 1 possible sequence: ['B1', 'B2'] (the dict key is not relevant).

For key 'A' there are 3 possible sequences: ['A1', 'A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A5']

For key 'C' there are 2 possible sequences: ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C4']

It is very difficult to formalize this problem, I hope these sequences are correct :)

So, what I expect is this output, a list containing ALL the possible sequences in the tree in the form of a list of phrases:

```
[
   ['A1', 'A2'],
   ['A1', 'A3', 'A4'],
   ['A1', 'A3', 'A5'],
   ['B1', 'B2'],
   ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
   ['C1', 'C4']
]
```

I don't need any particular order in the resulting list, I want only the sequences.

Thank you very much, every help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have no code to post because I have difficulty in understanding HOW to achieve the result. I tried both iterative and recursive approach but with no success because I am missing the main understand of how to do that, I'm sorry.

Comment: Wrt _" I tried both iterative and recursive approach but with no success"_ - great, add that code to your question. Doesn't matter that it didn't work or doesn't work well - otherwise you wouldn't have asked the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem.

First we make a function to go from the lists you have to a dictionary structure:

```
def convert_to_dict(conversation_list):
    dict_ = {}
    for sublist in conversation_list:
        dict_[sublist[0]] = convert_to_dict(sublist[1:])
    return dict_

print(convert_to_dict([['A1', ['A2'], ['A3', ['A4'], ['A5']]]]))
# {'A1': {'A2': {}, 'A3': {'A4': {}, 'A5': {}}}}
```

Then we make a function that takes this dictionary and returns the conversations in it:

```
def conversations(rv, lst, conversation_dict):
    for key, value in conversation_dict.items():
        if value != {}:
            rv = conversations(rv, lst + [key], value)
        else:
            rv.append(lst + [key])
    return rv

print(conversations([], [], {'A1': {'A2': {}, 'A3': {'A4': {}, 'A5': {}}}}))
# [['A1', 'A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A5']]
```

And then we can combine the two in a function that takes your dict and returns all the conversations:

```
def get_conversations(dict):
    rv = []
    for _, value in dict.items():
        dict_ = convert_to_dict(value)
        rv += conversations([], [], dict_)
    return rv

dict_ = {
   'A': [ ['A1', ['A2'], ['A3', ['A4'], ['A5'] ] ] ],
   'B': [ ['B1', ['B2'] ] ],
   'C': [ ['C1', ['C2', ['C3'] ], ['C4'] ] ]
}
print(get_conversations(dict_))
#[['A1', 'A2'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A4'], ['A1', 'A3', 'A5'], ['B1', 'B2'], ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], ['C1', 'C4']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's EXACTLY what I need and it worked perfectly! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function for a shorter solution:

```
d = {'A': [['A1', ['A2'], ['A3', ['A4'], ['A5']]]], 'B': [['B1', ['B2']]], 'C': [['C1', ['C2', ['C3']], ['C4']]]}
def get_paths(t):
    a, *b = t
    if not b:
       yield a
    yield from [[a, *(i if isinstance(i, list) else [i])] for j in b for i in get_paths(j)]

r = [i for [a] in d.values() for i in get_paths(a)]
```

Output:

```
[['A1', 'A2'], 
 ['A1', 'A3', 'A4'], 
 ['A1', 'A3', 'A5'], 
 ['B1', 'B2'], 
 ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'], 
 ['C1', 'C4']]
```